# What is the equivalent of CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration in .net core 3 or 5?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-6.0

CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration.

Official definition - Authenticated connections whose token sets the ExpiresUtc value will be closed and allowed to reconnect when the token expires.

It was introduced in .Net core 6. What is the equivalent of this in .Net core 3 or 5? If not what are the other options to achieve this?
I want to make sure whenever token expires it is disconnected and only upon fresh token receipt it gets connected

Comment: Hi @joker22, I suggest you can check [this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5283#issuecomment-368864944).